# Plone collections criteria. Can they be case insensitive or regular expressions?

Tags: regex, plone

I want to create a collection based on the title of content for any content that includes the string "mission report".  This could be in any combination of case and the separator could be a space, dash or underline.

An easy solution would therefore be a regex (or equivalent) on the Text search criteria.  Is there any way to do this?  * seems to work as a wild-card but that's about it.

I could add multiple criteria, but these seem to be ANDed and I can't see any option to OR them.  Is there a way to OR collection criteria?

The alternative would be to enforce a tag on all relevant content, but if I can avoid going down that road that would be great.

Answer (score 3):

Collections are built on top of the Plone [ZCatalog](http://plone.org/documentation/manual/developer-manual/indexing-and-searching/introduction-to-zcatalog) indexing tool. They basically represent canned queries.

As such, they are also *limited* by what the catalog can do. The Plone catalog only can do `AND` searches. It's Title index is already a full-text search index, with stemming and case-insensitive matching, but there is no index type that supports regular expression searches.

There is an [`AdvancedQuery` add-on](http://plone.org/documentation/manual/developer-manual/indexing-and-searching/searching-with-advancedquery) that at least supports `OR` queries too, but you'd have to create a custom sub-class of Collections to be able to use that tool.

Answer (score 0):

The content of any content object should be indexed in the SerachableText index. That index is a text index that will tokenize and make everything case insensitive already.